# Express in standard polar form

Tags: complex-analysis

How is the below expression converted to standard polar form:

$z=j+e^{\pi/4}$

Does the order matter, since j is at the beginning?

Comment: Is $j$ the imaginary unit ($j^2 = -1$)? We usually use $i$, but we have no trouble using $j$ instead, as long as we get a heads-up.

Comment: What is $j$ in standard polar form?

Comment: Yes $j$ is the imaginary unit. That is why i am getting confused cuz it has the format of the polar form, but i don't understand, this is how the book asks.

Comment: @Shkodrani Are you sure, what is $\sin \pi$?

Comment: Upss my bad :). I'll edit now my answer. Thnx @Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the *polar form* of a complex number $a+bj$ is given by $$r(\cos(\theta)+j\sin(\theta)),$$ where $$r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2},\quad\cos(\theta)=\frac{a}{r},\quad\sin(\theta)=\frac{b}{r}.$$

For $j+e^{\pi/4}$, we have $a=e^{\pi/4}$ and $b=1$. So, plugging this in to our definitions gives $$r\approx 2.41,\quad\cos(\theta)\approx0.91\quad\sin(\theta)\approx0.41,$$ therefore the polar form of $j+e^{\pi/4}$ is, to two decimal places $2.41(0.91+0.41i).$

Answer (score 1):

"it has the format of the polar form" No, it doesn't. It has the format of a real part ($e^{\pi/4}$) and an imaginary part ($j$), added together. This is often called "rectangular form", or "cartesian form". I don't know which name your book / lexcturer uses, but it's probably on of those two.

You convert to polar form the same way you convert any other complex number given in rectangular form: by finding its distance from the origin using the Pytagorean theorem, and finding its angle against the real axis using the inverse tangent function.

Don't let the fact that the real part is an exponential fool you. $e^{\pi/4}\approx 2.19$, so what you have is (approximately) the same as $2.19 + j$, and that's it.

Does it matter whether $j$ is first or not? In some sense it matters a lot, and in another sense it doesn't matter at all. For someone hung up on using formulas, and looking at the "first term", the "second term", and inserting these in the order they appear, then order definitely does matter. $j + e^{\pi/4}$ is the more uncommon order, so it's likely to confuse some of those who aren't completely confident with complex numbers. On the other hand, by definition of the symbol $+$, the two numbers $j+e^{\pi/4}$ and $e^{\pi/4} + j$ are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$z=x+jy=e^{\pi/4}+j\cdot 1\implies x=e^{\pi/4} \quad y=1$$

from here we can find

- $r=|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
- $\theta = Arg(z)$